# Oh boi! Dis aint Engliz! #1

Tags: wordplay, cipher, knowledge, language, word-problem

*First some Engliz:*

These weird combination of letters are actually words translated in some different languages, and concatenated.

Each line has one word translated in different languages. These nine words form three groups of three words each, with groups separated on the basis of a common relation.

What you have to do:

- Find the words
- Find the languages
- Find the groups

Since this question is the first part of a series of questions I'll be posting, so this one has a couple of easy workarounds.

> 1. rukamapaditupalapaainadaimntawvqhia
> 2. makrateliguraizeakjiandaokawilitxiab
> 3. kaghaldipaperazhipepantawv
> 4. mzeeguzkiataiyanglahnub
> 5. varskvlaviizarxinghokuhnubqub
> 6. dedamitsalurradiqiuhonuantiajteb
> 7. pankariarkatzaqianbipenikalamemhluav
> 8. kompasiiparrorratzaluopanpapunilibkoobqhia
> 9. zghvisitsasoahaikekaihiavtxuv

---

Knao sum non Engliz:

Da magick wond laees heir

> [Abrakedavra hocus pocus](https://translate.google.com)

Remememememember : Thou shant weight four hintz. Asck four'em.

Eeven partial ansirs ar olso welkome.

---

The second puzzle in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80360/57435).

Comment: Are all 9 lines an individual word? Or do all three rules apply to each line?

Comment: Each line has **one word** translated in different languages and concatenated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Languages**

> 1. Georgian
> 2. Basque
> 3. Chinese
> 4. Maori/Hawaiian
> 5. Hmong

Translated words appear in this order of translation.

**Words**

1. > **Map**
   >  - რუკა (ruka)
   >  - mapa
   >  - 地图  (ditu)
   >  - palapaaina (?)
   >  - daim ntawv qhia
2. > **Scissors**
   >  - მაკრატელი (makrateli)
   >  - guraizeak
   >  - 剪刀 (jiandao)
   >  - kawili
   >  - txiab
3. > **Paper**
   >  - ქაღალდი (kaghaldi)
   >  - papera
   >  - 纸 (zhi)
   >  - pepa
   >  - ntawv
4. > **Sun**
   >  - მზე (mze)
   >  - eguzkia
   >  - 太阳 (taiyang)
   >  - la (ra?)
   >  - hnub
5. > **Star**
   >  - ვარსკვლავი (varskvlavi)
   >  - izar
   >  - 星 (xing)
   >  - hoku
   >  - hnubqub
6. > **Earth**
   >  - დედამიწა (dedamitsa)
   >  - lurra
   >  - 地球 (diqiu)
   >  - honua
   >  - ntiajteb
7. > **Pencil**
   >  - ფანქარი (pankari)
   >  - arkatza
   >  - 铅笔 (qianbi)
   >  - penikala
   >  - memhluav
8. > **Compass**
   >  - კომპასი (kompasi)
   >  - iparrorratza
   >  - 罗盘 (luopan)
   >  - papuni (?)
   >  - libkoobqhia
9. > **Sea**
   >  - ზღვის (zghvis)
   >  - itsasoa
   >  - 海 (hai)
   >  - ke kai
   >  - hiavtxuv (hiav txwv)

**Groups**

> - Scissors, Paper, Pencil are **items used for arts/crafts or school supplies**
>  - Map, Compass, Sea are **all related to Sea Navigation**
>  - Sun, Star, Earth are **all objects in Space**

I'm missing the relation, they look like they're all related to

> arts and sciences.

Comment: Just answer sniped me. Well done.

Comment: @ZanyG, I still don't have the final relation though, so feel free to answer. :)

Comment: The way I read the question, there is no final group. The 'common relation' is between the groups of three words, which you've already answered.

Comment: @ZanyG, then maybe it's done then. Thanks so much. Well done to you too kind Sir :)

Comment: Yay! Also, @ZanyG is right. There is no final relation. But maybe I'll give one in next questions in this series.