# Oh boi! Dis waas never Engliz! #2

Tags: cipher, knowledge, language, word-problem

This puzzle is second in the series, the first one being [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80313/57435). But these are related in no way.

Below are some weird combinations of letters, which are actually words translated in some different languages, and concatenated.

> - Each line has one word translated in different languages.
> - These 22 words lead to new groups of words. For example if two of the lines translate to **Mount** and **Everest**, the new group
>   will be **"Mount Everest"**.
>
> *There can also be words like **"eel", "on" , and "must"**, which on arranging, sound or look like a group, which is **Elon Musk** in this
> case.*
>
> *There will be 10 groups of two words, and two groups as individual words, to have a total of 12 groups* (Let this set of groups be called Class A)
>
> - The groups from class A are related in a way, and can further be grouped, making a total of 4 B-classes, with each having 3 members from class A.
> - There is also a superclass C, which contains everything in class A and B.

**What you have to do:**

> 1. Find the languages
> 2. Find the 12 members of class A
> 3. Find the 4 members of class B
> 4. Find the only member of superclass C

---

Words below:

> 1. tartiblashukuhlungavargakirimasortuvannya
> 2. sirrahasyasekretimfihlo
> 3. kusaginnayiochlikindlalaholodni
> 4. qishebusikasitakalayazyma
> 5. honcharumbumbikumbalkarukulol
> 6. vihiluvakijokerhazillashadiganzhartivnyk
> 7. zalizotemirinsimbiyakada
> 8. haritayashilrangdaoluhlazazelenyy
> 9. lyudynakishiminisaumuntu
> 10. dveridoraeshikumnyango
> 11. likhtarilangachiroqvesakkuduva
> 12. pryntsisikhulushahzodakumaraya
> 13. dyvnogalatiokungajwayelekileamutu
> 14. kridaihryimidlalooyinlar
> 15. simyettihataisikhombisa
> 16. yonibturadiukukhanyasaeneliyaspalakh
> 17. phuthumashoshilingikmankarannapospishayte
> 18. kapelyukhisikhwamashapkatoppiya
> 19. shifokorlikaryaudokotelavaidyavarayek
> 20. khubekadampledumbletushibqolish
> 21. askarsoldatisoshasoldaduvek
> 22. manobirozkancanekuda

Da magick wond laees heir

> [Abrakedavra hocus pocus](https://translate.google.com)

---

Even partial answers are also welcome!

**Do not trust Google translate if it translates the whole combination to a word. It might be misleading. Confirm it by translating the words separately. For example, it translates qishebusikasitakalayazyma to alchemist, but it isn't.**

**Some hints:**

> #20 - Your eyes are belong to me. It do not need a translation.
>
> #3 - Brother of #10 is always against me.
>
> #7 - I've felt fear twice while you were reading this. Well I feel it was thrice
>
> #9 - What quite a lot of superhero's names have
>
> #22 + #12 - C'est une traduction Française

**Edit:** Assume you have 3 'The' s available.

Comment: could you please check if 4 was correct coz i have one very similar in mind. thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton yes 4th is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This puzzle appears to be extremely well-developed and thought-out for a new user, and I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: To clarify, each given line should contain the same english word, but translated into various different languages and concatenated together?

Comment: @AHKieran yes you are right.

Comment: Are the languages the same in each line? And is the order the same?

Comment: @Mohirl No they are not in the same order, but the languages are same in each line.

Comment: Ah!!! Thanks, that makes more sense now. Excellent puzzle, thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The languages are

> Uzbek, Sinhala, Ukrainian, and Zulu

Here are the words I have so far:

> 1. Sorting (tartiblash / ukuhlunga / varga kirima/ sortuvannya)
>  2. Secret (sir / rahasya / secret /  imfihlo)
>  3. Hunger (kusaginnayi / ochlik / indlala / holodni)
>  4. Winter (qish / ebusika / sita kalaya /zyma)
>  5. Potter (honchar / umbumbi / kumbalkaru / kulol)
>  6. Joker (vihiluvak / ijoker / hazillash / adiganzhartivnyk)
>  7. Iron (zalizo / temir / insimbi / yakada)
>  8. Green (harita / yashil rangda / oluhlaza / zelenyy)
>  9. Man (lyudyna / kishi / minisa / umuntu)
>  10. Door (dveri / dora / eshik / umnyango)
>  11. Lantern (likhtar / ilanga / chiroq / vesak kuduva)
>  12. Prince (prynts / isikhulu / shahzoda / kumaraya)
>  13. Strange (dyvno / galati / okungajwayelekile / amutu)
>  14. Game (krida / ihryi / midlalo / oyinlar)
>  15. Seven (sim / yetti / hata / isikhombisa)
>  16. Flash (yonib turadi / ukukhanya / saeneliya / spalakh)
>  17. Hurry (phuthuma / shoshiling / ikman karanna / pospishayte)
>  18. Hat (kapelyukh / isikhwama / shapka / toppiya)
>  19. Doctor (shifokor / likarya / udokotela / vaidyavarayek)
>  20. Dumble (khubeka / dample / dumble / tushib qolish)
>  21. Soldier (askar / soldat / isosha / soldaduvek)
>  22. Little (mano / biroz / kancane / kuda)

Class A:

> We know 20 of these are pairs and two remain alone, for 10 + 2 = 12 members of Class A.
>  Class A members are: Sorting + Hat, Winter + Soldier, Hurry (Harry) + Potter, Iron + Man, Green + Lantern, Dumble + Door, Doctor + Strange, Flash, Joker, Hunger + Games, Little + Prince, Secret + Seven.

Class B:

> Winter Soldier, Iron Man, and Doctor Strange are all **Marvel** characters.
>  Green Lantern, Joker, and Flash are all **DC** characters.
>  Sorting Hat, Harry Potter, and Dumbledore are all **Harry Potter** characters.
>  Little Prince, Secret Seven, Hunger Games are all **Children/Young Adult** books.

Superclass:

> These are all **fiction.**

Comment: You got the correct language, and all the correct words except #20. #21 is also correct. One of your groups is **almost** correct(hint: well.. Read the question again). Btw it's a good progress!

Comment: Yeah, I've got a feeling about how some of the Group A members fit into Group B (e.g. rot13(pbzvp obbx punenpgref)) but I wanted to get all 22 clues down first in case I jumped too quickly to an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: Well not exactly. But this contains two group B classes as each class B contains 4 members.

Comment: All good. I had incorrectly numbered hint for  #20 as #2. Also, it is exactly not like a hint, but sort of an instruction. A Google search with #12 might result in #22.

Comment: I'm so stuck on #3. I figured that going for the groupings might help make clear what 3 is supposed to be, but as you can see I'm still stuck seeing how those last ones fit together (assuming my other guesses for the B groups are correct). And the only thing I can see right now for the supergroup is rot13(fbzrguvat eryngrq gb 'svpgvba') but I can't be sure.

Comment: Yes you have the correct superclass and 3 correct B classes. One of the hints in the question gives one of the groupings, and consider the plural of #14. I've also edited the question to have the exact name of the last groups.

Comment: Got it! Updated with #3 and all my guesses for the groupings!

Comment: Yay!!! Finally it is complete! Congratulations and thanks for attempting such a long puzzle. (In the beginning I wasn't even sure if anyone would do this). Have a good day!

Comment: I wasn't sure if I'd do the whole thing, I just wanted to get the first couple down and let someone else finish it. Then I got obsessed. :D

Answer (score 2):

Very partial start

Languages:

> Russian/ish, ?, ?, ?. Zulu/Xhosa/ish

2

> dver|idoraeshikum|nyango - door

9

> lyudy|nakishiminisa|umuntu - people

20

> khubek|adampledumbletushib|qolish - stop, stay

21

> askar|soldati|soshasoldaduvek - soldiers - looks like it should break along sosha|solda|duvek but can't find matches

Comment: Your first language is not exact, but close. The fourth one is on the right track. It is one of those which you mentioned.

Comment: #2 is right, though you have incorrectly broken the first word. #4 is very very close, but again you have incorrectly broken the first word.

Comment: In all the words, you have broken them almost correctly, but missed by a letter or two. #21 has the right meaning, but the second translation is incorrect by a letter. But meaning of #20 is incorrect.

Comment: Do you want hints to any specific line? Because I'll be editing the question with some hints shortly.